# Best way of setting up Web3 instance in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, blockchain, web3js

**What is generally best practice way to set up a web3 instance?**

- `useRef`
- `useState`
- Using/not using `useEffect`

- Using props/context to pass a single instance to other components, or re-instantiating it in each component

---

Background: I tried setting up a web3 instance with `useRef`, however it only passed `null` through context. I found though that using `useState` and *not* using `useEffect` worked. Curious about best practice though.

```
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

  /* ⨯ Passed through context as null */
  const web3 = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      web3.current = new Web3(window.ethereum)
    }
  }, [])

  /* ✓ Passed through context as web3 instance */
  const [web3, setWeb3] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      const w3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)
      setWeb3(w3)
    }
  }, [])

  /* ✓ Passed through context as web3 instance */
  if (window.ethereum) {
    const w3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)
    setWeb3(w3)       // ✓
    web3.current = w3 // ✓
  }

  return (
    <Web3Context.Provider value={web3.current ?? web3}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Web3Context.Provider>
  )
}
```